# Can there be two non-isomorphic sets of permutations with a one-to-one match between i's in S1 and k's in S2 (see description)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

In thinking about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175183/algorithm-to-find-isomorphic-set-of-permutations) — where sets of $M$ permutations of length $N$ ($M<N$) are defined as "isomorphic" if one [permutation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_one-line_notation) can be found that, when applied to each permutation in the first set, converts the first set to the second set of permutations — I came up with the following:

If two sets are isomorphic, it means a one-to-one mapping exists, where the set of all the numbers at index $i$'s in set $S_1$ equals the set of all the numbers at some index $k$'s in set $S_2$. *My conjecture is that there are no two non-isomorphic sets with this property.*

Can someone prove or disprove this?

*Isomorphic example*: The permutation $[3,2,1]$ (or $[1,2,3]$) converts $S_1 = \{[1,2,3],[3,2,1]\}$ to $S_2 = \{[3,2,1],[1,2,3]\}$

*Non-Isomorphic example*: The set $S_1 = \{[1,2,3],[3,2,1]\}$ cannot be converted to
$S_2 = \{[2,3,1],[1,3,2]\}$ by only one permutation.

Comment: What do you mean all $i$s in $S_1$ are the same as all $k$s in $S_2$? Do you mean $S_1=S_2$? I don't understand your property. I think this is what you mean, but it's hard to tell. If this is what you mean then it is clearly false for single element sets, so... Anyway, clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: @jgon thank you for reading, please see this question and my answer to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175183/algorithm-to-find-isomorphic-set-of-permutations - it means the set of numbers at index `i` from all the permutations in `S1` equals the set of all the numbers at some index `k` in set `S2`.

Comment: In your answer you don't conclude 0 and 1 are isomorphic sets, but they are, use the permutation that switches 2 and 3.

Comment: In fact this is the conversion between your $S_1$ and $S_2$ above in your Non-Isomorphic example.

Comment: @jgon please show a full counter-example - show the permutation so I can understand what you mean - I could not verify your suggestion about switching 2 and 3, it seems wrong,

Comment: Oh actually maybe I'm getting confused about this notation...

Comment: @jgon this is the definition I use for "permutation function" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_one-line_notation

Comment: I'm confused here. How are you applying permutations? Is it function composition, or are you treating the other permutations as lists?